# Aren't There a Maximum Recommended Size Of Given Home Partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition

Going to format some free space in `ext4` file system, but currently in doubt about its size.

Aren't there a maximum recommended size for it?

Something like a good manner, for example: "`home` partitions shouldn't be larger than 400gb`.

Comment: There is _no way_ anyone can give a "recommended size for the `/home` partition".  This has to be something that you decide on yourself after thinking about and examining your ordinary home directory space requirements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Considering that a file system is and electronic fragile structure, it may be wiser to do not keep all files in only one partition, in case of file system error.

Having conditions, it should be better to divide in smaller ones, if possible.

Comment: Au contraire; the more partitions, the greater the chance one of them will get corrupted. Instead, backup, then verify the backup; backup again to different media and verify.

Comment: En réalité: LOL.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [ext filesystem developer's wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), the maximum size is one exbibyte, or 1,048,576 TiB, assuming a 4 KiB block size; files with a 4 KiB block size can be as large as 16 TiB. The ext3 limit of 32,000 directories has been removed; there is no limit on the number of directories in ext4.

There's no formal 'best practice' suggesting a maximum size.